# You need to enable Javascript - React App

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, iis, .net-core

I have a ASP.Net Core Web Application with React that I built on Visual Studio 2019. I'm now trying to deploy on a Windows Server 2019 Standard IIS.

I followed all the steps to get that deployed and now when viewing the site, the webpage just displays a white screen. When inspecting the page I see a `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.`

From reading other posts I'm seeing the issue can be related to my package.json, startup.cs, or web.config. I've posted my code for all three. Do I need to run `npm build` on the server?

Or maybe something with my ports?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "testcalendar",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "material-table": "^1.69.1",
    "merge": "^1.2.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.4.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "xml-js": "^1.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.9.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.3",
    "nan": "^2.14.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace TestCalendar
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url=".*" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="/dynamotoolsapi" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>                
            <aspNetCore processPath=".\TestCalendar.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: b6025f4d-4dd5-4a9a-8094-a8e221a9799a-->
```

Comment: does your browser have the javascript disabled? try enabling it and try again

Comment: @Jerryc don't think it has anything to do with my browser unfortunately. Tried it on multiple browsers, on different computers.

Comment: that text is always available by default in the `index.html` page for a standard `create-react-app` application. If this is the case, you have been investigating incorrectly and the problem maybe something else.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar any idea where I should start investigating?

Comment: firstly, does it work with the simple `npm start` ( the one where react start a node server with hot reloading enabled, often called the developer mode ). If yes, then `npm build` it and copy the static files onto your server and try again, make sure that the URL is the same as the one as you interacted in the `npm start`, if they are not the same, please add an additional `homepage` key in the `package.json` and try again.

Comment: Can your Application work locally? Or will it encounter problems when deployed on iis? First, please check if JavaScript is enabled in your browser.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar so I built this project in `Microsoft Visual Studio` so everything in there is running and working I can do npm start and npm build. However, I now published the project and am trying to load on a windows server this is where I'm getting this issue

Comment: can you try to host this on a nodejs server? if it works there and doesn't work on .NET it means that there is some configuration issue, however, if it doesn't even work on a node server, then the React code might have some issues, possibly the URL routing.

Comment: Can you get other related error messages?  Try open Dev Tools (F12) and looking for errors in the console or network tab. Is there any error message in the Event Viewer?